# C# Neo4jClient: An unhandled exception of type 'System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException' occurred in IO.dll

Tags: c#, neo4j, neo4jclient

Just like the title says. I keep getting this exception after an hour or two of running a program I have that is loading data into the database. If I stop the program and restart it, everything works fine...until it happens again.

Here are some screen shots of what I can provide...

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I've done a search and I have seen others having this same problem over the years, but no one has really provided an answer (or so it seems).

Thoughts?

Comment: You get this from only calling `Connect() `?

Comment: Nope, I have a try catch around that and that's there the exception is being caught after X long (I haven't timed it to see if it is consistent yet). This is a class declared in a "Using" statement. Each time a file is opened, it's contents are read, I declare the Using statement to work with this open connection to neo4j while I have content to push to the DB. After the data has been pushed, the using statement closes, I open the next file and establish a new connection. This happens several times before the exception happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who are wondering the same, the issue was that I wasn't disposing of the client as I was deposing of my own object. So I believe the different connections were just expiring and the exception was being thrown.

Such a rookie mistake I should have caught before now :-(